# Feature importance using lightgbm

Tags: python, python-3.x, lightgbm

I am trying to run my lightgbm for feature selection as below;

initialization

```
# Initialize an empty array to hold feature importances
feature_importances = np.zeros(features_sample.shape[1])

# Create the model with several hyperparameters
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(objective='binary', 
         boosting_type = 'goss', 
         n_estimators = 10000, class_weight ='balanced')
```

then i fit the model as below

```
# Fit the model twice to avoid overfitting
for i in range(2):

   # Split into training and validation set
   train_features, valid_features, train_y, valid_y = train_test_split(train_X, train_Y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = i)

   # Train using early stopping
   model.fit(train_features, train_y, early_stopping_rounds=100, eval_set = [(valid_features, valid_y)], 
             eval_metric = 'auc', verbose = 200)

   # Record the feature importances
   feature_importances += model.feature_importances_
```

but i get the below error

```
Training until validation scores don't improve for 100 rounds. 
Early stopping, best iteration is: [6]  valid_0's auc: 0.88648
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (87,) (83,) (87,)
```

Comment: How do you initialize feature_importances ?

Comment: @FlorianMutel see th eupdated post

Comment: What is features_sample ? How many features do you have ? I cannot reproduce your bug with Iris data for example.
It seems you are trying to add arrays with different shapes.
Either you initialized with wrong dimensions, or some of your features become empty (all nan), or constant when you are splitting your data (train / valid), and lightgbm ignores them. Try looking at your splits!

Answer (score 27):

An example for getting feature importance in `lightgbm` when using `train` model.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

def plotImp(model, X , num = 20, fig_size = (40, 20)):
    feature_imp = pd.DataFrame({'Value':model.feature_importance(),'Feature':X.columns})
    plt.figure(figsize=fig_size)
    sns.set(font_scale = 5)
    sns.barplot(x="Value", y="Feature", data=feature_imp.sort_values(by="Value", 
                                                        ascending=False)[0:num])
    plt.title('LightGBM Features (avg over folds)')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig('lgbm_importances-01.png')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: feature_imp = pd.DataFrame({'Value':model.feature_importances_,'Feature':self.x_cols})

Comment: `feature_imp = pd.DataFrame({'Value':model.feature_importances_,'Feature':X.columns})`

Answer (score 8):

Depending on whether we trained the `model` using `scikit-learn` or `lightgbm` methods, to get importance we should choose respectively `feature_importances_` property or `feature_importance()` function, like in this example (where `model` is a result of `lgbm.fit() / lgbm.train()`, and `train_columns = x_train_df.columns`):

```
import pandas as pd

def get_lgbm_varimp(model, train_columns, max_vars=50):
    
    if "basic.Booster" in str(model.__class__):
        # lightgbm.basic.Booster was trained directly, so using feature_importance() function 
        cv_varimp_df = pd.DataFrame([train_columns, model.feature_importance()]).T
    else:
        # Scikit-learn API LGBMClassifier or LGBMRegressor was fitted, 
        # so using feature_importances_ property
        cv_varimp_df = pd.DataFrame([train_columns, model.feature_importances_]).T

    cv_varimp_df.columns = ['feature_name', 'varimp']

    cv_varimp_df.sort_values(by='varimp', ascending=False, inplace=True)

    cv_varimp_df = cv_varimp_df.iloc[0:max_vars]   

    return cv_varimp_df
```

Note that we rely on the assumption that feature importance values are ordered just like the model matrix columns were ordered during training (incl. one-hot dummy cols), see [LightGBM #209](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/209).

Comment: +1, but Re:"feature_importance() function is no longer available in LightGBM python API"

Actually it is still there, I think you meant Scikit-learn API.

Comment: `feature_importance()` is still [there](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.feature_importance) indeed, I kindly suggest you update the answer accordingly.

Comment: This generalization should automatically detect which API was used for training and choose the appropriate method to get importance.

Answer (score 4):

For the LightGBM's 3.1.1 version, extending the comment of @user3067175 :

```
pd.DataFrame({'Value':model.feature_importance(),'Feature':features}).sort_values(by="Value",ascending=False)
```

is a list of feature names,within the same order of your dataset, can be replaced by `features = df_train.columns.tolist()`.
This should return the feature importance with the same order of plot.

Note: If you use LGBMRegressor or LGBMClassifier, you should use

```
pd.DataFrame({'Value':model.feature_importances_,'Feature':features}).sort_values(by="Value",ascending=False)
```

Comment: It's essentially a copy of my answer from 1 year earlier... arguably also less universal and less readable:) Nevertheless making it more universal and upvoting for the nice use of chaining (and for pluralism's sake).

Comment: One day my answer will be outdated as well, and very humble of you, thanks :=)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to examine a loaded model that you don't have the training data, you can get feature importance and the feature name by

```py
df_feature_importance = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'feature': model.feature_name(),
        'importance': model.feature_importance(),
    })
    .sort_values('importance', ascending=False)
)
```